# Newly created mdadm raid 6 cannot be mounted

Tags: mount, raid, mdadm

I have a newly created mdadm raid 6 that was built using this command:

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md127 --level=6 --raid-devices=8 /dev/sdi1 /dev/sdj1 /dev/sdk1 /dev/sdl1 /dev/sdm1 /dev/sdn1 /dev/sdo1 /dev/sdp1
```

it shows when I use lsblk:

```
sdi         8:128  0   7.3T  0 disk  
└─sdi1      8:129  0   7.3T  0 part  
  └─md127   9:127  0  43.7T  0 raid6 
sdj         8:144  0   7.3T  0 disk  
└─sdj1      8:145  0   7.3T  0 part  
  └─md127   9:127  0  43.7T  0 raid6 
sdk         8:160  0   7.3T  0 disk  
└─sdk1      8:161  0   7.3T  0 part  
  └─md127   9:127  0  43.7T  0 raid6 
sdl         8:176  0   7.3T  0 disk  
└─sdl1      8:177  0   7.3T  0 part  
  └─md127   9:127  0  43.7T  0 raid6 
sdm         8:192  0   7.3T  0 disk  
└─sdm1      8:193  0   7.3T  0 part  
  └─md127   9:127  0  43.7T  0 raid6 
sdn         8:208  0   7.3T  0 disk  
└─sdn1      8:209  0   7.3T  0 part  
  └─md127   9:127  0  43.7T  0 raid6 
sdo         8:224  0   7.3T  0 disk  
└─sdo1      8:225  0   7.3T  0 part  
  └─md127   9:127  0  43.7T  0 raid6 
sdp         8:240  0   7.3T  0 disk  
└─sdp1      8:241  0   7.3T  0 part  
  └─md127   9:127  0  43.7T  0 raid6
```

But I can't mount it, istead I get this error:

```
$sudo mount /dev/md127 temp

NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/md127': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/md127' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

What's wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you forget to make a filesystem (mkfs)? Hope you were not trying to recover old data.

Comment: Why does it think it's NTFS? That's worrying - it's like you've almost got some instance of a previous filesystem there

Comment: lol, yup, I had forgotten to make the filesystem. Thanks! Also, they were used drives, but I was not trying to recover data.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have forgotten to create a filesystem on that array after activating it.